# Does Rstudio put '.Rproj.user' and '.Ruserdata' in '.gitignore'?

Tags: r, git, rstudio

Whenever I use git with R / Rstudio, the `.gitignore` file appears to contain two items by default: `.Rproj.user` and `.Ruserdata`. I don't want to change this, I just want to understand why it happens. Is it some kind of Rstudio default? I normally make commits via the integrated terminal, but I never explicitly add anything to `.gitignore` myself.

A clarifying follow up question: What would I have to do to prevent this from occuring? I'm guessing that if I wrote a `.RProj` and some `.R`s using notepad and pushed via a standalone Git bash I would retain an empty `.gitignore' in my project directory.

Hope that all makes sense, thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it some kind of Rstudio default?

Yes. RStudio (rightly) assumes that you probably don’t want to commit user-specific configuration.

> What would I have to do to prevent this from occuring?

Rather than attempt to prevent it, you can simply edit `.gitignore` and remove the entries of files that you want to commit. That said, I would generally advise *against* this, as these files *shouldn’t* be committed.

Comment: The problem is that RStudio keeps adding those entries each time it launches. I have `.Rproj.user` git-ignored in a global git configuration and would appreciate RStudio not including unsolicited lines to my projects' `.gitignore`. I usually end up giving up and letting the line there. But my collaborators don't use RStudio and while it doesn't hurt, it is not very elegant.